# passing a javascript variable to a php function and quoting it correctly

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

Im using Zend Framework ..in one of my phtml file's i have this code

```
<script>
 function foobar(id,type){
   var idarray =  <?php AppNamespace_General::getparentids( ?>id, type<?php ) ?>; // here  the id and type are from js
//the php function returns a json array to the js variable
 ......
  location.href = baseurl +'/somepage/id/'+id;
   }
```

How can i correctly pass the js elements to the php function

The php function(Already thought of doing it via ajax..its quite complex)

```
public static function getparentids($id, $type, $elmarray = '') {

        if (empty($elmarray)) { //avoiding redeclaration of array
            $elmarray = array();
        }
        switch (strtolower($type)) {
            case 'group':
            case 'product':
            case 'specification':

                $gp_handler = new PackAssist_Model_DbTable_Groups();
                $q = "SELECT * FROM t_groups WHERE group_id = $id";
                $sql = $gp_handler->getAdapter()->query($q);

                break;
            case 'part':
                $pt_handler = new PackAssist_Model_DbTable_Parts();
                $q = "SELECT * FROM t_parts WHERE part_id = $id";
                $sql = $pt_handler->getAdapter()->query($q);
                break;
        }
        $result = $sql->fetchAll();
        $i = 0;
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                if (isset($row['group_parent_id']) && $row['group_parent_id'] != 0) {
                    if (in_array($row['group_id'], $elmarray)) {
                        $e = $row['group_parent_id'];
                    } else if ($row['group_parent_id'] != 0) {
                        $e = $row['group_id'];
                    }
                } else if (isset($row['part_group_id'])) {
                    $e = $row['part_group_id'];
                } else if ($row['group_parent_id'] == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                if (isset($e) && !empty($e)) {
                    array_push($elmarray, $e);
                }
                self::getparentids($e, 'group', $elmarray);
                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            array_push($elmarray, $id);
        }
        array_pop($elmarray); //removing the group of super parent group which we dont need

        if ($i == 0) { // just encode the array only once
            echo json_encode(array_reverse($elmarray));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the statement? I don't think this will work as `php` tags are already parsed and rendered when the `js` comes into scene on client side and the `foobar` is called.

Comment: What isn't being passed correctly? That _should_ work shouldn't it?

Comment: @jcolebrand its not working as it shows syntax error

Comment: @The village idiot the php function returns a json array to the js variable

Comment: @ubercooluk Could you explain a little better what you're trying to do? What I see is, you're trying to pass JS vars `id, type` to the PHP function `getparentids` back to the JS function `foobar`. If that's so, you'll need some Ajax as all php in the page is processed before outputting any HTML/JS code.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté ..ill update my answer with that php function..

Comment: Yes, you need to use ajax to make this happen. What you've done with the PHP won't work here. Do you understand how to do AJAX?

Comment: Yes Ajax is one of my daily dishes..but check that function it has a recursive call..how do i do that with ajax

Comment: Any help in converting the php function to ajax would be highly appreciated

Comment: As has been already pointed out, PHP is processed server-side, so when your JS is executed there's no PHP code in it anymore. For Ajax, you'll have to fetch a `JSON` response from the PHP and, on the Ajax call's completion/success, call your `foobar` function passing the `response` data as parameter.

Comment: Ajax is not a problem for me..but my php function has a recursive call (calling that function in that function again)..how can i do that in ajax..hava alook on my php funtion

Comment: Oh I see. your function is recursive only until it gets all results, right? You'll get the response containing all data inside the `$elmarray` when the Ajax completes.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes the $elmarray is a json string ..the function will call multiple times until it gets all the results

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with that, you should get your expected `JSON` object as the PHP will only output the `JSON` when it finishes processing. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, or do you mean how to convert it to Ajax? Just copy and paste your function to a new php file then call it once passing the `POST`/`GET` data from Ajax as parameters to your function. =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, you can do the following to execute the JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/path/to/script.php',
    data: '{ id: '+id+', type: '+type+' }',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
         dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
         // process data
    },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
});
```

You can use your existing PHP code with this solution.  The url you point to would just have to print the JSON result, as you are currently doing in `getparentids()`.